# How to use descriptive flexfield context in table based value set in Oracle EBS

Tags: oracle, oracle-apps, oracle-ebs

for a descriptive flexfield in Oracle E-Business Suite, I would like to register a new segment (global or context specific) with a table based value set. In the where clause of the value set, I would like to reference the flexfield context.

Is there any way to achieve this? I tried the :$FLEX$ modifiers, but they don't seem to work for the context of the flexfield, but only for segments. I've also tried :BLOCK.ITEM, but that is not exactly what I am looking for here.

Specifics:

- descriptive flexfield with context = AUDIO
- either globally or for the context AUDIO, I have registered a new segment and assigned my table based value set
- where clause of the value set:

  ```
  WHERE attribute1 = <FlexField Context>
  ```

The only solution I can currently see is to have a dedicated value set for each flexfield context where I can simply write

```
    WHERE attribute1 = 'AUDIO'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with attribute_category it holds dff context information.